# Is there a way to check the actual SATA II/III connection of your drives?

Tags: windows, ssd, sata

I have an Acer Aspire M3985 with a B75 chipset, IPIMB-AR rev 1.02A MoBo, which is supposed to have one SATA 3 and five SATA 2 ports. I tried using CrystalDiskInfo, HD Tune and AIDA64 to understand if my four SATA 3 drives have a SATA 2 or 3 connection, but these software seem to report the device type instead.

The issue is that the drive connected at SATA0 (blue one supposed to be SATA 3) is an SSD and shows speeds up to 240MB/s Seq Read and 70MB/s Write in CrystalDiskMark. The disk is Kingston A400 120GB (the worst I could get), but it is supposed do go beyond 300 in read and 200 in write.

[image]

Is there a way to check the effective SATA connection (SATA 2 or 3) of your drives from windows ?

Also do you have any suggestion regarding the SSD poor speed results ?

This is the test result reported in a Kingston A400 review :
http://vishveshtech.blogspot.com/2017/04/kingston-a400-240gb-ssd-review.html

[image]

Rest of the system:
i5-3470
16GB DDR3-1600
W10x64Pro
TRIM is enabled

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: Edit. Is there a software showing the effective SATA connection (SATA 2 or 3) of your drives ?

Comment: Yes;  However, the only one, that comes to mind is written by a company that cannot be trusted since it was sold.  Questions seeking software recommendations are also out of scope here at Superuser.

Comment: I said software but i meant some way of telling besides a speed test and the actual port. Also any suggestion on why the drive is slow is welcomed

Comment: Several of the PCs I've used have had the option to change SATA speed per port in the BIOS.  Separately, if you have another SATA3 device that is satisfactorily fast on another PC, you can put it into the PC in question, using the same cable as the "slow" drive.

Comment: @alfred - There is no other way except to use software or to perform a speed test.  One of those methods you have already performed.

Comment: @alfred Take a look at [this graph](http://webblack.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/d069b5618f293ccaae83edcaec628b04.jpg). A400 is TLC (like most now), which is actually quite slow. To speed up they use a small SLC cache. The max size of the A400 cache is 4gb but it may (Samsung does, couldn't find if Kingston does) shrink as the drive becomes more full.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  On Windows you can use some freeware utilities such as HWiNFO: https://www.hwinfo.com/
Reference: https://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-tell-the-storage-controller-is-sata-2-or-sata-3-on-windows

On linux you can get this info from the system log:
{code}
dmesg | grep -i sata | grep 'link up'
{code}
Reference: https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-fast-is-linux-sata-hard-disk.html

In some systems the BIOS might also tell you, though it depends on your motherboard.

Comment: It says the SSD is working @ 6Gb/s so I have to look elsewhere for the poor performance

Answer (score 0):

Speccy by Piriform also shows the current transfer mode and is a bit more friendly, I would actually advise it above HWiNFO.

NB. Be careful not to also install ccleaner or chrome with it.